# How is the correct form to model a reference/pointer to a class in UML?

Tags: c++, uml

You have two classes: class A and class B.

In order to become an instance, Class B needs to have a member, that is an object of class A. And, class B has all the features of class A, excluding the functionality that allows to modify the object of class A.

Also class B has some extra features, and the reason, not to make this using inheritance is because if an object of class A (that where use to instance B) is changed, therefore the values of the instance of class B, must also be changed.

I represent this behavior with an aggregation, but there are some things I am not sure about. One is when the object of class A is destroyed, the object of the class B is not (even it does not make sense the object B any more, and access to some of it features will provoke a run time failure).

With this I meant that an object of class B references an object of class A, and not the other way around, like in a normal aggregation where normally object will contain an object of class B.

It this will mean that it is not an aggregation but a composition? even if the object don't make any sense after the end of the lifecycle of the referenced object? or how this behavor should be model instead?

Answer (score 1):

Look here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation

Aggregation on the contary does not imply ownership. This is your situation.

What about behavior of your object after destruction of aggregated object, this does nothing with class diagram.

Comment: But the problem is that when the object a is destroy the object b is not, but it not make any "sens", stil exist but is inconsistance and should not be use. In reality this in my program it will never happend if is use correcly. In the example in wikipedia say if a department is destroy not it profesors but this is so because  the profesors are strong enough to live itself. My case is not so, object b is nonsens after object a dies.

Comment: @user1739342 the real question is why you have such object =)
If it should not be there, than it should not be there. Relationship of your object looks like `dependency` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Dependency